# Why does a call to interface method not work with Capitalized-name-reference to interface instance?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

Please help me, I can't run the program because of this error.

> Non-static method `onClicked(int)` cannot be referenced from a static context.

Code

```
public class ProfileAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ProfileAdapter.myViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<Profile_Info> infos;
    Context context;
    MyClickedInterface myClickedInterface;


    public ProfileAdapter(ArrayList<Profile_Info> infos, Context context, MyClickedInterface myClickedInterface) {
        this.infos = infos;
        this.context = context;
        this.myClickedInterface = myClickedInterface;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ProfileAdapter.myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.my_profile,parent,false);
        return new myViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ProfileAdapter.myViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(infos.get(position).getAppName());
        holder.imageView.setImageResource(infos.get(position).getImageResource());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return infos.size();
    }
    public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView textView;
        ImageView imageView;
        public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView =(TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
            imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    MyClickedInterface.onClicked(getAdapterPosition());
                }
            });
        }

    }

    interface MyClickedInterface{
        void onClicked (int position);
    }
}
```

Comment: here --> MyClickedInterface.onClicked(getAdapterPosition());

Comment: You need to read the error output, and research the error details if you don't understand it (or at least post error output here).

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call `onClicked` via your interface `MyClickedInterface`, instead call it using the instance `myClickedInterface`

Replace

```
MyClickedInterface.onClicked(getAdapterPosition());
```

with

```
myClickedInterface.onClicked(getAdapterPosition());
```